# Unable to produce message when leader is not available

Tags: apache-kafka

I am unable to produce message when Leader is not available. I created new topic with replication factor 2 using below command

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181  --topic TestTopic202  --partitions 1 --replication-factor 2
```

Then

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TestTopic202
```

Output:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropri
ately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
Topic:TestTopic202      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
Topic: TestTopic202     Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
```

After creating topic I stopped broker-1 which is leader of this topic to test fault tolerance. I expected broker-2 will be elected as leader but I received broker down error message.

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 34.93.59.30:9092 --topic TestTopic202
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
>Hi
```

After bringing down,

```
^C[kafka@hgtestsrv1 ~]$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic202
\OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
>Hi
[2019-09-03 12:25:47,305] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-09-03 12:25:47,407] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be ava
ilable. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-09-03 12:25:47,511] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be ava
ilable. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-09-03 12:25:47,765] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be ava
ilable. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-09-03 12:25:48,222] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be ava
ilable. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
^Corg.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:862)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:839)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.send(ConsoleProducer.scala:75)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:57)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Requested metadata update after close
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.awaitUpdate(Metadata.java:200)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:982)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:859)
        ... 4 more
```

Can anyone tell me how to test fault tolerance?

My *server.properties*

```
default.replication.factor=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before producing a message to Kafka, Kafka fetches metadata regarding how many partitions are there for that topic and which broker is the leader for which partition etc.

**Approach #1.** Now, it is important to **give your bootstrap servers** (broker list) of the producer to the broker that is reachable. You said, you have brought broker-1 down, so you cannot include it as the *only one* in your Kafka producer bootstrap servers.

The following configuration needs to be changed.

```
bootstrap.servers=<IP>:<Port>
```

Set this to your broker-2 and see.

For your question of testing fault tolerance...

Your approach is right, but you must include multiple (if not all) brokers in your producer/consumer `bootstrap.servers` property.

You gave `localhost:9092` Is this the broker which you brought down? Where is the other broker running? The running broker must be given to the producer.

Check to see if the other broker is running and is registered with the same zookeeper.

**Update:**

You gave 2 different IPs `34.93.59.30:9092` and next `localhost:9092`, I suspect that they are two different brokers on two different machines.

**Approach #2.** *If it is the case*, ensure that (as said before) your `localhost:9092` broker is registered with the zookeeper of `34.93.59.30:9092` broker (*It should mostly be registered with `34.93.59.30:2181` if you use the default ports*).

So in the `server.properties` of your `localhost:9092` (your second broker you should give the same zookeeper as your broker-1).

```
zookeeper.connect=34.93.59.30:2181
```

and foremost, ensure that your `localhost` can connect to that first.

**Approach #3.** If you still were not able to figure this out check the output of your describe topics.

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TestTopic202
```

after you brought the broker-1 down. It should show you the leader.

Comment: ThanK you.. Your approach 1 worked for me.. Now I need to do the same  using dotnet confluent kafka. Could you please tell me how to do we give both broker's IP in producer config?